# How do I find the points of discontinuity in a function with e?

Tags: calculus

Here is the function: $$\frac{1}{1+e^{1/x}}$$
I need to find the point(s) where the function is discontinuous. I already know how to do that with most functions, but this is the first time I've encountered an e.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only point of discontinuity of the real function
$$
 f(x):=\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac1x}}
$$
is at $x=0$.
You have, for $x\rightarrow 0^-$,
$$
 e^{\frac1x}\rightarrow 0, \quad \text{and}\quad f(x)\rightarrow 1,
$$
whereas, for $x\rightarrow 0^+$,
$$
 e^{\frac1x}\rightarrow +\infty, \quad \text{and}\quad f(x)\rightarrow 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\ f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{1/x}}$$
$$\text{The function is not defined for }\ x=0 \text{ so we take }\lim_{x\to0}f(x) \text{and see what happens:}$$
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{1+e^{1/x}}=\frac{1}{\infty}=0 $$
$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1}{1+e^{1/x}}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\infty}}=\frac{1}{1+0}=1$$
$$\text {so the function is not continuous for x=0, there is a jump discontinuity}$$